# How possible to have a peak current at zero voltage

Tags: energy

In a physics text book a graph of the applied voltage, the cemf, and the current are displayed. The applied voltage and the counter voltage are 180 deg. out of phase. When the current is at peak value both the applied voltage and the cemf are at zero. How is it possible to have maximum current flow at zero voltage?

Comment: Can you, please,  explain what the term "counter voltage" means? Which  is probably related to your acronym cemf.

Comment: Have you read the chapter(s) in the textbook on AC circuits?

Answer (score 0):

In AC circuits with sinusoidal voltages and currents, you can easily have a 90 degrees phase shift between current and voltage. For example, when you apply an ac voltage to a capacitor, you will get the following relation between current $I$ and voltage $V$ written as phasors $$ I=i\omega C V$$ This means that the sinusoidal current is ahead in phase with respect to the current by 90 degrees so that the current reaches its peak value when the voltage is going through zero.